# ASP.NET MVC 4 Facebook FacebookContext - How to get reference

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

Today I've been trying to program a little bit in the MVC 4 Facebook API developed by Microsoft (based on the example of: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app)

So far I managed to manipulate the MyAppUser model, etc. Everything working fine and as intended. I only have a slight problem when I'm switching through controllers.

Is there any way to retain the FacebookContext object through controllers?

Unfortunately the above example (from Microsoft) only loads MyAppUser in the Home controller as follows:

```
    [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();
            return View(user);
        }

        return View("Error");
    }
```

What should I do if I use another controller in the application? How can I obtain a FacebookContext reference to get the user?

Things I tried:

Putting FacebookContext context into the other Controller (is always null)

Putting the FacebookContext object into Session or ViewBag - no avail, and sounds way too dirty anyway.

Am I missing something crucial here?

I just wanted to have a different Controller with a couple of actions to manage a User's profile, which would be done completely separately from Facebook's data (via a database hosted locally.) The only reason I need to load the Context is to get the current user's e-mail address to create their account on that basis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've spent quite a considerable amount of time trying to fix it.

My example controller could be:

```
        public ActionResult Manage()
    {
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<Models.MyAppUser>();
            if (MyDALFunction.GetUserByMail(user.Email) == null) {
                // Create user functions, create a ViewModel, pass it on and do some editing.
            }
            return View(user);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved this:

First, in Home Controller I save access token to TempData

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.TempData["accessToken"] = context.AccessToken;
```

Then I read it in another action in different controller. If access token is empty, it means that user is not logged in, so I redirect him to Home controller.

```
        var accessToken = TempData["accessToken"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            //if access token is null or user is not logged in, redirect to home controller
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(accessToken);
            var me = fb.Get("me") as Facebook.JsonObject;  //current logged user
            var userFacebookId = me["id"].ToString();
```

Instead of "id", you can read email.

**EDIT**:
Retrieving accessToken from `TempData` returned `null`, when i tried to do that in another controller. It would be better to store it in `Session` instead.

[Where to store Facebook access token in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883971/where-to-store-facebook-access-token-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks so much. I abandoned using the framework but this might be useful for other people. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, for answering too late.. but if i understood your question correctly then i think you are trying to get the FacebookContext object in you Action Method when post-back occurs. If so, then.. In your .cshtml try to put

```
<a target="_top" href="@GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppUrl@Url.Action("Manage", new { friendId = friend.Id })" role="button" class="btn btn-success">
```

and then make you action method like...

```
public ActionResult Manage(string friendId, FacebookContext context)
{
    var friend = await context.Client.GetFacebookObjectAsync<MyAppUserFriend>(friendId);
    // var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<Models.MyAppUser>();
    if (MyDALFunction.GetUserByMail(friend.Email) == null) {
        // Create user functions, create a ViewModel, pass it on and do some editing.
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

But Make sure that your **MyAppUserFriend** model have the Email attribute..
If you wanted any thing else then please provide some detail of you **Model** and your **View**