# Where to store Facebook access token in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables

In my ASP.NET MVC app, when I authenticate the user with OAuthWebSecurity, Facebook sends back an ExtraData which contains the access token. Initially I thought of storing this in the database, but it says in the FB docs:

> You should also remove the stored access token.

...when logging the user out.

So the token should be handled as a session variable, but in ASP.NET MVC I don't have session variables (or there are ways, but it's not a good pattern). What is the best way to store the FB user acess token for the session duration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with using the session, and what do you mean by not having a session and "there are ways"?  Controller has a Session property.  Should be easy to store & retrieve your token in there.